# Upgrading Angular 1.2 to 1.4, controller registers but doesn't run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

**Solved!** It turns out that the project had console.log suppressed, meaning that poor JavaScript was trying to show me errors and failing. Once I got logging back on I was able to see that there actually were errors preventing the controller from running. I can get errors from ng-strict-di now, too. There was in fact an injection that wasn't working right. I'm still not sure what this has to do with the new version of Angular but at least I have an idea how to fix it.

I am working on upgrading my project from using Angular 1.2.9 to 1.4.8, and I've run into a bug that has me stumped. When I load up the site running 1.4.8, my controller gets registered on the app module, but the controller function never runs.

```
app.controller('TemplateCtrl',
    ['$scope',
     //other injections, etc.
function ($scope)
{
    //there's a real controller here
     console.log('The controller loaded!');
}]);
```

In the shortened example above, a breakpoint on line 1 (app.controller()) will hit, but a breakpoint on line 7 (console.log()) won't. The baffling thing is that everything works normally in 1.2.9; it's only when switching to 1.4.8 that this bug crops up. Surely Angular didn't change something as basic as controller registration across versions!

[ng-inspector output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ1W3.png)

As you can see from the screen grab, ng-inspector shows that the controller has been registered, but thinks it has no scope variables.

I've already gone through and made every fix that I can see to update my code to match the new version. (There weren't many, just some uses of $cookies in a different file.) All my angular modules (ngRoute, ngSanitize, ngCookies) are also updated to 1.4.8. I've also updated all the other libraries the project is using (jQuery, ui-bootstrap, and bootstrap's js). I've even tried taking out jQuery and bootstrap, thinking they might be unnecessary (I inherited this project from someone who was not really an Angular dev, so the code is a mess). I don't get any errors in the console.

Any ideas what's happening? I'm happy to answer any questions or add information I can.

**Edit 1:** The controller is currently called thus: `<html ng-app="CorsApp" ng-controller="TemplateCtrl">` where TemplateCtrl is the controller in question and CorsApp is the app it's being registered on. If it wasn't clear from my initial question, swapping in Angular 1.4.8 in the bundler in place of 1.2.9 is the only change I've made, which takes the project from working to failing.

**Edit 2:** I've done a few more things to try to hunt this down. First, I removed all js libraries other than plain old Angular 1.4.8. So no jQuery, no ui-bootstrap, no ngRoute, etc. The bug still occurs.

I've also been chasing the issue down the js call stack and it appears that the bug occurs right after the DOMContentLoaded event fires. Based on the order my breakpoints are hit, the js files referenced in my html are all loaded and then the DOMContentLoaded event fires. (In other words, exactly what you'd expect.) After that event, the appropriate controller (TemplateCtrl as above) isn't running, despite the file having been read and the controller apparently being registered. It's like the scope just isn't loaded up.

[Just before the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyrWE.png)

This screen grab captures the moment right before the bug shows up. As far as I can tell this is basically the last thing that happens before the browser says OK, we're done, render everything! So it may have nothing to do with the bug at all.

**Edit 3:** So I tried replacing the controller that wouldn't run with a brand-new, tiny little one and what do you know! It loaded fine. I can't find any suggestion that Angular has a limit to the size/length of controllers or any such thing, but it's a thought. At least I can guess that the controller itself is doing something that offends 1.4.8 but not 1.2.9.

Comment: Stupid question - you do have some kind of ng-controller or a directive with using this as its controller somewhere? Because (just an assumption) why should angular run the controller function if it is not used?

Comment: Oh! Yeah, the controller is currently called thus: `<html ng-app="CorsApp" ng-controller="TemplateCtrl">` where TemplateCtrl is the controller in question. I'm not crazy about these being on <html> but I haven't gotten the okay to change things around yet...

Comment: Actually, there *have* been changes to the way that controllers are registered, which occurred between 1.2 and 1.3.  However, based on the limited code you have provided so far, it doesn't appear you are doing it the old way anyway.  That being said, there are some things that can be tricky to troubleshoot.

Comment: There is a newer attribute that you can use with the `ng-app`, which will perform some additional analysis and report problems with dependencies : `ng-strict-di`.  This is safe for production, as it just outputs extra diagnostic info.  simply add it to the same element as your `ng-app` (probably the `<html>` element), and see if it reports any dependency issues.

Comment: here is a plunker that the angular team put together to illustrate `ng-strict-di`:  http://plnkr.co/edit/fhseUa8Go2oaHQlcctOT?p=preview

Comment: @Claies, that's right, I did see that registering controllers directly on the window was eliminated. You're correct that this app doesn't use that pattern, thank goodness!

Comment: ng-strict-di didn't turn anything up, but that's a great tool that I'd never seen before. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately it isn't ideal to try to do troubleshooting through comments.  Ideally, if you had 50 rep, we could have a conversation through chat that would allow us to collaborate on troubleshooting.  However, I have a few suggestions, and I'll *try* to make the best use of comments as possible.

Comment: first, you are showing the variable assignment pattern for the module assignment (`app.controller`).  This can be problematic, especially if you have the `app` variable in use across multiple files.  You might accidentally overwrite `app` in one of the files, causing the previously registered controllers to be unavailable. It is much better to use the module getter/setter syntax.  (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#getters)

Comment: for what it's worth, there is a wealth of information in that style guide.

Comment: @Claies, as I mentioned in my question I inherited this code and I don't yet have permission to make all the changes I'd like to. I'm a huge fan of Papa's style guide but whoever originally wrote this app definitely wasn't! :) The heart of my question is really that however poorly written, the app works fine with Angular 1.2.9. It's only when upgraded to 1.4.8 that it breaks.